# Application fails when only one of two Active Directory server is off

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2

When I unplug the Ethernet cable of one of the Active Directory servers, my application fails to authenticate user, despite there is a different Active Directory server is available on the network.   Why is that? I expect that if one of the Active Directory  servers fails, the other ones can handle requests.

I use Windows Server 2008 R2 64-bit.

I have an IIS application which authenticates users against an Active Directory.

```
        string serverName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AD.Server"];
        string userName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AD.User"];
        string password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AD.Password"];
        _principalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, serverName, userName, password);
```

Here are the configuration settings:

```
<add key="AD.Server" value="192.168.0.1"/> <!---  THIS IS THE PRIMARY PRODUCTION SERVER -->
<add key="AD.User" value="Domain\Administrator"/>
<add key="AD.Password" value="******"/>
```

Then I set up another Active Directory server (let it be 192.168.0.2).  It successfully syncs with the production server. Later, when I switch the second AD server off, my application fails with exception "The server is not operational".

Why is that?  Why does the application depend on the second server, despite being explicitly given another server in config?

Comment: string serverName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AD.Server"];
So is this AD.Server the server you unplugged by chance?

Comment: Are both servers setup as global catalog servers?

Answer (score 2):

Your DC's should work the way you are expecting.

- Run ***DCdiag /a***, does it report any failures?
- If you restart your app when the "working" DC is offline does it work, presumably now pointing at the other DC (i.e. is it an either or issue where it's binding to one DC at start and then can't rebind to the other when the one it's using is unavailable)?
- How long has the new DC been up - IIS needs to have a chance to be aware it exists.
- You should not need to specify a Domain Controller - you should point your app at the domain, not a server.

I am a little confused at what is happening, in your question first you say you expect it to fail over yet you are explicitly telling it which DC to use. If you need to provide a server name try the domain's DNS name itself (company.local or whatever). This will resolve to a list of IPs for each DC in your domain.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set all your computers in Active Directory to know about that secondary domain controller IP address? You do that in DNS section of your network configuration.

Comment: A question like this makes more sense in a comment, not in an answer.

Comment: Can't comment till 50 reputation.